# Chrome dev tools: Accessing the DOM element $0 pointer from bookmarklet/Snippet

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to access the $0 DOM element pointer from bookmarklet or snippet in console.?

More info about $0

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#0_-_4

> Dev Tools remembers the last five DOM elements (or JavaScript heap objects) that you've selected in the tab (or Profiles panel). It makes those objects available as $0, $1, $2, $3, and $4. $0 returns the most recently selected element or JavaScript object, $1 returns the second most recently selected one, and so on.

Comment: Your question contains "in console", to that the obvious answer is yes, since if you copy any javascript code that has $0 and run it in the Console tab of DevTools it will work, but not on the bookmarks bar.

Comment: It's supported now in Snippets. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48124238/1669860).

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a way to do this too.  I haven't found one, but I found a good compromise to be a bookmarklet that copies a snippet of code to my clipboard.  I use $0 with angular a lot to get the scope of an element, like this: angular.element($0).scope()

So I have a bookmarklet that copies that line to my clipboard, then I can very easily paste that into the console.  Depending on what you want to use $0 for, maybe that will do the trick for you.

Here is a link to how to copy text to clipboard with javascript:
[How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: It's supported now. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48124238/1669860).

Answer (score 0):

In the bookmark I simply used `angular.element(this.document)` instead of `angular.element($0)` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working as of Chrome 65.

I've got a Snippet that runs:

```
console.log('$0 points to', $0);
```

In the GIF (Right-click > **Open Image In New Tab** if it's too small) you can see that the reference gets updated every time that I select a new element and then re-run the snippet. FYI I'm running the Snippet from the [Command Menu](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ui#command-menu) by typing `!` followed by the name of the script.

[image]